# Direct credit card payment not working in paypal codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, credit-card

I have implemented paypal standard gateway in codeigniter. If the user have paypal account, its working fine, but If the user dont have paypal account, direct credit card payment not working in codeigniter. Its always showing

```
[data:PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException:private] => {"name":"PAYEE_ACCOUNT_INVALID","message":"Payee account is invalid.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#error-PAYEE_ACCOUNT_INVALID","debug_id":"b56a875be1599"}
```

But the same credentials working fine for whose having paypal account. pls give me suggestion.

I need solution for this paypal issue

Answer (score 0):

The integration you are attempting to use ([v1/payments for direct cards](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/)) is very old and no longer supported by PayPal for new integrations. Your account does not have permission to use it, and will not be given permission, hence "Payee Account Invalid" since it cannot be used with that account.

Use a current [standard checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) or [advanced](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/) integration instead.

Comment: Can you have any code for codeigniter, I am new to this, can you please suggest me any code for codeigniter. Above given link showing in reach noce js codes only. Thank you

Comment: search the web for examples, or paste each of the node.js sample files into an LLM and ask it to convert to PHP/Codeigniter as a start

Comment: ok thank you @ Preston PHX